# jQuery-autocomplete with Spring

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

My JavaScript code can't connect to the Spring controller:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nombrePais').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'getTags',
    paramName: "tagName",
    delimiter: ",",
    minLength: 3,
    transformResult: function (response) {
      return {
        suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function (item) {
          return {
            value: item.nombre,
            data: item.idPais
          };
        })
      };
    }
  });
});
```

I tried both: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTags` and `getTags` in the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="getTags", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List <Pais> getTags(@RequestParam String tagName) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Entre :)");
        List <Pais> paises = timbreDAO.findAllPaises(tagName);
        return paises;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: 1) this is not specific to jQuery-autocomplete; 2) what and how fails to work? What's the error message? 3) use your browser's Network tab to examine the URL sending your request to (you can also use your browser's address bar to try to figure out the correct one). 4) Is your web.xml correct?

Comment: Can you check your browser console for the ajax call made what response you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this.its works for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tsrId').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl: 'YOUR_URL.html',
                paramName: "tagName",
                delimiter: ",",
                transformResult: function(response) {
                return {suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {return { value: item.name, data: item.id };
                   })};}});});
</script>
```

in Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/YOUR_URL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<TSRMaster> getTsrId(@RequestParam String tagName) {
    ----------
    return tsrMasterList;
}
```